# Make uft function read datatable consonant parameter from jenkins

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I'm new at programming and started to learn how to work whit UFT (whit vb script) and Jenkins.
I'm trying to pass a parameter so the function created gets the data from excel file, accorded the parameter. At sheet one we have Particular users, and at sheet two we have business users.

I know we can set an Input Parameter, but i don't know exactly how this works so it changes the type at the function, and how to configure Jenkins to send these parameters when running the build.

Basically if function is:

```
Getuser(type)

If Type = "P" Then      
DataTable.ImportSheet LocalFicheiros & "LOGIN\input.xlsx", "Particular", "Global"
Else

DataTable.ImportSheet LocalFicheiros & "LOGIN\input.xlsx", "Business", "Global"

End If
```

Read a lot about this, but started to get confused to me.

Comment: What does [tag:android] have to do with this question?

Comment: I just put some to try, and forgot to edit. Ty for the warning. Edited to UFT and Vbscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this by using a `vbscript` which creates the `UFT` instance and runs the required test.  Jenkins uses a `cscript` call to execute this script.  The `vbscript` accepts the parameters in the call from Jenkins and passes them into the `UFT` script (using the `ParametersCollection` of the created instance) which is configured to accept the input parameters and pass them into the appropriate actions.